# MS Sql Date format?

Tags: sql-server

I'm pretty new to MSSQL and was wondering if someone could help me convert the following where statement from looking at previous week to previous month.

```
ks.report_date BETWEEN (convert(varchar(113), (DATEADD(day, (-1 * DATEPART(dw, (dateadd(week, -1, getdate())))) + 1, (dateadd(week, -1, getdate())))), 101))
                        AND (convert(varchar(113), (DATEADD(day, (-1 * DATEPART(dw, (dateadd(week, -1, getdate())))) + 7, (dateadd(week, -1, getdate())))), 101))
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a function called EOMonth() that will take a date and give you the end of the month containing that date.  You can then use DATEADD to subtract months from that value to get the last day of previous months. Lastly, use DATEADD again to add 1 day to get the first day of the month.  Here is an example.

```
BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -2, EOMONTH(GETDATE())))
AND  DATEADD(MONTH, -1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an earlier version than SQL Server 2012 then this would work:

```
BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
AND DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```